# UITableViewCell - content reset when scrolling up or down

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, scroll, swift2

I have this problem where data values on my prototype dynamic UITableViewCell are reset when scrolling up or down.

I am checking for cell is nil as suggested in other threads since cells are reused but execution never hits that if.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Currency formatter
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "el-GR")

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "MenuItemTableViewCell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuItemTableViewCell

    if cell.isEqual(nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "MenuItemTableViewCell") as! MenuItemTableViewCell
    }

    // Match category (section) with items from data source
    let itemsPerSection = items.filter({ $0.category == self.categories[indexPath.section] })
    let item = itemsPerSection[indexPath.row]

    // cell data
    cell.cellTitle.text = item.name + "  " + formatter.stringFromNumber(item.price)!
    cell.cellDescription.text = item.description
```

Any help please?

Regards,
Polis

Comment: Is the cell content reset while it's on screen? What exactly is happening? This method seems fine, what other method are implemented that interact with the table view?

Comment: yes, the reset happens when i scroll down and then back up again. for example i have a custom stepper control with a label representing quantity of a menu item (food). i set it to 2, scroll down (so that the cell is out of view), scroll back up again and it's 0. i have multiple sections in my tableview so I am also implementing titleForHeaderInSection and numberOfRowsInSection. Nothing special really.

Comment: I had this problem before. I now use kingfisher open source framework & it works great. Plus it supports asynchronous image that will make your app a lot faster without any code from your side

Comment: @WassimSeifeddine thx, will look into that, never came across it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a cell goes off screen and back on again the cell is re-created.  So if you modify the cell (i.e., as you describe with the stepper) you must save that modified value so that it is created with that modified value the next time it comes on screen.

Comment: Could you share an example please? When / where would I save the modified value (i.e. which delegate method) and how would I know if the next time a cell comes to the screen is a new one or the same one? This is where my confusion lies really.

Comment: Every single time the cell goes off screen, when it comes back on screen you will get a call to `tableView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.  This means that the variables you use to set the cell's values in `tableView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` must always be up to date.  You would update them in response to the user manipulating the value (i.e., the `IBAction` of the stepper, in the case you describe).